# How can I fix my code to work my dispatch with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use Redux, and I have some problem with dispatch. It doesn't work like it should work. When i dispatched some information, finally I have in state an empty array, but it should be array with object.

It's my code:

```
if(printDrawingsRedux.imagesCounter.length === 0) {
    //Создаём массив для идентификации кол-ва резервируемых блоков под фото    
      
      const arrNew = fd.map((value, index) => {            
        let result    
        return result = {...value, id: index, link: false, quantity: 1,
                                                                      type: value.type,
                                                                      name: value.name,                                                                     
                                                                      blackWhitewRateCost: 50,
                                                                      colorRateCost: 100,
                                                                      drawingPages: [],        
                                                                      currentNumberPage: 1,
                                                                      howManyPages: function () {
                                                                        return this.drawingPages.length
                                                                      },
                                                                      modalPlusSize: false, 
      }
      })
        
      dispatch(setImageCounterDrawingsRedux(arrNew))
      console.log(printDrawingsRedux.imagesCounter) 
      
  }else{   
      const arrNew = fd.map((value, index) => { 
           
        let result    
        return result = {...value, id: index, link: false, quantity: 1,
                                                                      type: value.type,
                                                                      name: value.name,
                                                                      blackWhitewRateCost: 50,
                                                                      colorRateCost: 100,
                                                                      drawingPages: [],        
                                                                      currentNumberPage: 1,
                                                                      howManyPages: function () {
                                                                        return this.drawingPages.length
                                                                      },
                                                                      modalPlusSize: false,
      }
      })
      
      let newState = [...printDrawingsRedux.imagesCounter, ...arrNew]      
     
      let arrNew2 = newState.map((value, index) => {
        return {...value} = {...value, id: index}
      })
      dispatch(setImageCounterDrawingsRedux(arrNew2))        
  }
  

  //Делаем итерацию по созданному массиву для наполнения контентом

  const promiseArrayBuffer = (file) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = (e) => resolve(e.target.result);
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
        
  (async function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < fd.length; i++) {
      console.log("Hello2")
      if (fd[i].type === "image/jpeg" || fd[i].type === "image/jpg" || fd[i].type === "image/png" ){        
        console.log("Hello3")
          const arrayBuffer = await promiseArrayBuffer(fd[i]);
          var image = arrayBufferToBlob(arrayBuffer, fd[i].type)         
          
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(image);
          
           
          let arrNew = printDrawingsRedux.imagesCounter.map((value, index) => {
            if (index === i) {
              return {...value} = {...value, link: url, drawingPages: {drawingSize: "А3 (297х420мм)",
                                                          kindPrintDrawing: "чорно-білий друк",
                                                          thicknessPaperDrawing: "80 г/щ",
                                                          commentForPage: "",
                                                          quantityDrawing: 1,
                                                          personalSize1: 0,
                                                          personalSize2: 0,
                                                          quantity: 1,
                                                          pageNotToPrint: false,
                                                          personalSizeCounter: function () {
                                                          return this.personalSize1 * this.personalSize2 / 1000000
                                                          },
                                                      } }
              }else{
                return value
              }
            })                  
          dispatch(setImageCounterDrawingsRedux(arrNew))

      }else {
        console.log("pdf catched")
      }       
    }})();
```

eventually have an empty array in Redux state instead of array with object

```
                                                                    {id: index, link: false, quantity: 1,
                                                                      type: value.type,
                                                                      name: value.name,
                                                                      blackWhitewRateCost: 50,
                                                                      colorRateCost: 100,
                                                                      drawingPages: [],        
                                                                      currentNumberPage: 1,
                                                                      howManyPages: function () {
                                                                        return this.drawingPages.length
                                                                      },
                                                                      modalPlusSize: false,
                                                                      }
```

but if I delete part with async function it dispatch well, but with async function I finally get an empty array in state.

my action to this dispatch:

```
export const setImageCounterDrawingsRedux = (files) => {
    
    return {
        type: SET_IMAGECOUNTER_ASYNC_DRAWING,    
        payload: files, 
    }
}
```

my reducer:

```
case SET_IMAGECOUNTER_ASYNC_DRAWING:   
            return {...state, printDrawings: {...state.printDrawings, imagesCounter: action.payload} }
```

Comment: My first question is: why does that one line have 3km of whitespace at the end?

Comment: Where? What do u mean ?

Comment: I can't read that code pal it's all over the place

Comment: Ok. Have a nice day. Goodbye.